# Does anybody know a video player I can use for my React Native project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Good Morning,

I'm creating an app/website that allows people to watch and create videos and I'm looking for a video player module that I can import into my project to use. Can you guys give me some recommendations on which video player is the best and which I can use?

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately questions asking for library recommendations are not allowed in Stack Overflow. In general, try searching for React Native video libraries, and then compare features, how recently updated and how widely used they are.

Answer (score 0):

I think react-native-video is the default video player package, but honestly I find it quite slow on loading external videos.